# how to find k nearest values to a value with hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to implement k-NN algorithm in java, I need to fetch k value with minimum distance to our value fron database.
for example, I entered 123, and we have 10000 value in database. I want to find 10 value with minimum difference from database.
how can I do this.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the values from the database ordered by the value of interest.